# How to Hide search box from xsltlistviewwebpart?

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2016, xslt-list-view-web-part, search-box

We are Migrated the VS solution form 2013 to 2016.

Sharepoint 2013 site searchbox are not displaying.

But in 2016 site all site pages searchbox are displaying.
(only searchbox present in xsltlistviewwebpart)

I want to hide the serachbox from css or masterpage ?
[image]
i added listview webpart from site definition

Cannot import this Web Part.
                  
                  
                      
                          $Resources:eContractsCore,My_Tasks_ListWebpart
                          False
                          True
                           True
                          True

Answer (score 3):

You can hide the search box by editing the webpart properties. Edit webpart--> Uncheck "**Display Search box**" (Under Miscellaneous)

[image]

If you are provisioning the webparts using modules into a page, you can edit the webpart xml and change property  **InplaceSearchEnabled** from True to False like below:

```
   <property name="InplaceSearchEnabled" type="bool">False</property>
```

Comment: I am adding webpart from site definition.there i am using this InplaceSearchEnabled is false. But still the search box are displaying.

Comment: i am using all site pages xsltlistviewwebpart. So in all pages in client site i can't do Edit webpart--> Uncheck "Display Search box"

Comment: this works until i refresh and then the box shows up again and the box is once again checked.

Comment: @user84385 did that work for you? 

I am on SharePoint 2016 on-prem and for me as well, it keeps coming back once I save the page